# Report folders' access

Tags: reports-api, access

**How can I check all the access(user/role) on the report folders?**

We can check the access level on the report folder and selecting the option "Share" and have the list of users/roles to which the folder has been shared.

But do we have an object from which we can select all the `UserOrGroupId` for all the report folders?

Comment: See, if the FolderShare object helps, I have never tried it individually. Click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009wUnIAI) for documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afraid not. In the official documentation for the "Access Type" field of the standard folder object, it says that "The API doesn't allow you to view, insert, or update which group or Role the Folder is shared with."

Please find the link for the official documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_folder.htm

Thanks